# Save image of multiple elements wpf

Tags: wpf, save, element

Wondering if there is an method to save the image of multiple (overlapping) elements in WPF. I know you can pass and element to something such as, 'bitmap.Render(visual)' but if we have for example a polygon and a circle on top of an image we would like to save the combined elements (eg: flatten these layers) and save the image to a file.

Comment: you should show what you have tried so far or explored and didn't work.

Comment: Pass the panel that contains all those (overlapping) elements to `RenderTargetBitmap.Render`.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is to create a new container such as a panel, remove the items from the existing one and add to the new one. Get the visual then add them back.

That or Clemens good comment on the original post.